# Playing 2 audio files consecutively

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I need to play 2 audio files, consecutively, when the first one ends, the seconds one needs to begin playing...

2 calls for playEffect() runs the files simultaneously.

```
SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playEffect("effect1.mp3") ;
SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->playEffect("effect2.mp3") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what it is supposed to do.

Off the top of my head, if you know the durations of each effect. You can play effect1 and schedule a method with delay of effect1's Duration. Once that method if called you can play the effect2.

It's dirty but it will work. :P